# How to get AccessVersion from C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, jet

How do I go about getting the AccessVersion?

I'm seeing references to objects with a 'properties' collection, but I have no idea what the object is.

For example http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321329

Related to the above, I guess my question is:  Is there a way to access the msado15.dll functionality without doing the interops myself?

I've been poking around the JRO COM object for .Net, and it doesn't seem to have what I'm looking for.

Ultimately, I just want to programmatically determine what the `JET` engine version is for a specific .mdb file.

Comment: I'm slightly confused: Do you want to know the "Jet engine version" that is installed on the machine, or do you want the `.mdb` file version (Access 2002-2003, Access 2000, ...)? Generally speaking, `.mdb` files are not tied to a specific "Jet engine version".

Comment: The .mdb file version.  I'm attempting to compact programmatically, but I don't know ahead of time what version each .mdb file is going to be.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the `.mdb` file version you can use the following VBScript/VBA code that I found [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/10/07/how-can-i-determine-which-version-of-access-was-used-to-create-a-database.aspx):

```
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Scripts\Test.mdb"

intFormat = objAccess.CurrentProject.FileFormat

Select Case intFormat
    Case 2 Wscript.Echo "Microsoft Access 2" 
    Case 7 Wscript.Echo "Microsoft Access 95"
    Case 8 Wscript.Echo "Microsoft Access 97" 
    Case 9 Wscript.Echo "Microsoft Access 2000"
    Case 10 Wscript.Echo "Microsoft Access 2003"
End Select
```

In C# you could add a reference to "Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library" (or similar) and then use some code like

```
var objAccess = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb");
int intFormat = (int)objAccess.CurrentProject.FileFormat;
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is only available on the machine if Access is installed?

Comment: @Fred Yes, only work if Microsoft Access is installed